# UITextView.text can't take a variable of type String?

Tags: swift

There are very confusion things going on...

I try to set a text from the UITextView via `UITextView.text = myVar` but this won't work, every time i run this code this exception is shown:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

let myStringVar: String = "I am a test string"

myTextView.text = myStringVar
```

But this peace of code works very well:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!

myTextView.text = "I am a test string"
```

Why is that so? Can anyone help me?

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: try let myStringVar: String? = "I am a test string". Note that string is set to optional

Comment: Maybe you're doing `myTextView.text = myStringVar` when the text view is not available yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

insert `print(myTextView)` before `myTextView.text = myStringVar` and check, if `myTextView` not nil.

Comment: thank you for the help, you are right the UITextView is nil